# Python 2 Layer Scoreboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a 2nd layer of "scoring" implemented into this simple scoreboard. I am so lost. I'm self taught so I am sure I am missing major steps.

Conditions: 3 points = 1 round. 10 rounds = Winner!

This is where I am at in the code. I can get it to count the points by pressing A or B, but when it reaches the "winRound" amount, in this case "3", nothing happens and it continues to count. :( I've spent the last 5+ hours on this and I'm about to give up. I know its something simple, but man it hurts the soul.

I'm trying to trigger the "round won!" so I know how this all works and I can continue.

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep


#fighters
fighter1 = "Jim"
fighter2 = "Ryan"

#points
point1 = 0
point2 = 0
winRound = 3

#rounds
round1 = 0
round2 = 0
winMatch = 10

#sleep time
sleepTime = 1

#defines the match being on
matchActive = True
roundActive = True


#scoreboard
def sb():
    print("Fighter:",fighter1,'\n','Points:',point1,'\n','Rounds:',round1)

#functions

while matchActive == True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        point1 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        point2 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)

while matchActive == True:
    if point1 >= winRound:
        print("Round Won!")
```

Honestly - I dont fully understand how python sees all this code. That may be the issue.

Edit: I got it all working, here is the final code:

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep


#fighters
fighter1 = "Mark"
fighter2 = "Jim"
fighter3 = "Tom"
fighter4 = "Rick"

#points
point1 = 0
point2 = 0
point3 = 0
point4 = 0
winRound = 3

#rounds
round1 = 0
round2 = 0
round3 = 0
round4 = 0
winMatch = 10

#sleep time
sleepTime = .25


def changeFighter1(fighter):
    fighter1 = str(input("Set Fighter Name"))


#scoreboard
def sb1():
    print(fighter1,":",round1,":",point1," |vs| ",point2,":",round2,":",fighter2)
def sb2():
    print(fighter3,":",round3,":",point3," |vs| ",point4,":",round4,":",fighter4)

#functions
def resetScores():
    f = open("fighter1points.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(0))
    f.close()
    f = open("fighter2points.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(0))
    f.close()
    f = open("fighter3points.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(0))
    f.close()
    f = open("fighter4points.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(0))
    f.close()


#match 1 start
sb1()

while round1 < winMatch and round2 < winMatch:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
        resetScores()
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        if point1 < winRound:
            point1 += 1
            sb1()
            sleep(sleepTime)
        if point1 == winRound:
            point1 = 0
            point2 = 0
            round1 += 1
            sb1()
            f = open("fighter1points.txt","w")
            f.write(str(round1))
            f.close()
        #if round1 == winMatch:
            #pass

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        if point2 < winRound:
            point2 += 1
            sb1()
            sleep(sleepTime)
        if point2 == winRound:
            point1 = 0
            point2 = 0
            round2 += 1
            sb1()
            f = open("fighter2points.txt", "w")
            f.write(str(round2))
            f.close()
        #if round2 == winMatch:
            #pass

#Match 1 Over
if round1 >= winMatch:
    print("\n",fighter1,"has reached",winMatch,"rounds!")
    print("Player 1 wins the battle!")
elif round2 >= winMatch:
    print("\n",fighter2,"has reached",winMatch,"rounds!")
    print("Player 2 wins the battle!")



#match 2 start
sb2()
while round3 < winMatch and round4 < winMatch:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
        resetScores()
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        if point3 < winRound:
            point3 += 1
            sb2()
            sleep(sleepTime)
        if point3 == winRound:
            point3 = 0
            point4 = 0
            round3 += 1
            sb2()
        #if round1 == winMatch:
            #pass

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        if point4 < winRound:
            point4 += 1
            sb2()
            sleep(sleepTime)
        if point4 == winRound:
            point3 = 0
            point4 = 0
            round4 += 1
            sb2()
        #if round2 == winMatch:
            #pass

#Match 2 Over
if round3 >= winMatch:
    matchActive = False
    print("\nPlayer 3 has reached",winMatch,"rounds!")
    print("Player 3 wins the battle!")
elif round4 >= winMatch:
    matchActive = False
    print("\nPlayer 4 has reached",winMatch,"rounds!")
    print("Player 4 wins the battle!")
```

Comment: #functions

while round1 < winMatch and round2 < winMatch:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        if point1 < winRound-1:
            point1 += 1
            sb()
            sleep(sleepTime)
        if point1 == winRound-1:
            point1 = 0
            point2 = 0
            round1 += 1
        if round1 == winMatch:
            print("Player 1 Wins!")
            matchActive = False

Comment: I hope my answer have helped, however there are lot of things in your code that are `unpythonic`. I am going to rewrite your code so that you can check the difference and learn how to use python

Comment: Definitely helped! I dont really know much of any one coding language, and just do my best to piece things together. I'm sure there is a lot that is wrong here :P.

Comment: also please upvote each others answers. Since I'm new - it wont let me do it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 2 `while`, but the actually you have to do all the work in 1 `while`. Your code still need some improvements but Use this code to fix the problem you are having:

```py
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        point1 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        point2 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)
    if point1 >= winRound:
        print("Round Won!")
        break
```

**Note**
Your code can be improved a lot, but as you are new programmer you should stick with what you have learned. However, you should take something into consideration right from the beginning:

- Always use naming conventions
- Write `pythonic` code i.e. no need for `while match_active == True` you can just write `while match_active`
- Create functions generic, use parameters, so that you can reuse same functions just tweaking some parameters around. See my code that reflects some of these points:

```py
import keyboard
from time import sleep

#fighters
fighter1 = "Jim"
fighter2 = "Ryan"

#points
point1 = 0
point2 = 0
win_round = 3

#rounds
round1 = 0
round2 = 0
win_match = 10

#sleep time
sleep_time = 1

#defines the match being on
match_active = True
round_active = True


#scoreboard
def sb(fighter, point, round):
    print("Fighter:",fighter,'\nPoints:',point,'\nRounds:',round,'\n')

#functions

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        point1 += 1
        sb(fighter1, point1, round1)
        sleep(sleep_time)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        point2 += 1
        sb(fighter2, point2, round2)
        sleep(sleep_time)
    if point1 >= win_round:
        print(fighter1, "Round Won!")
        break
    elif point2 >= win_round:
        print(fighter2, "Round Won!")
        break
```

Comment: This helped a bunch! thank you! Question, do I need to define a condition for if they meet the winMatch goal? In the code I have now, I have a section with if round1 == winMatch: Pass. Is this necessary? Or can I just get rid of it.

Comment: Oh also, with the functions. I've tried making a bunch and nesting them within each other - but ultimately the code failed. So I decided to take a step back and get the working code  going - then turn it into functions.

Comment: If you want to add 10 rounds you have to change structure of your code so that program keeps on running after a round is won. Add some more `whiles` here and there. I know you can do this. 
If you find this answer solving the problem, you must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then kindly mark 
that as answer. so that if someone have the same issue in future they can get a handy help without asking a new question. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)

Comment: I actually went even deeper and added two matches now. 4 fighters. Round 1 - 10, then resets and round 1 - 10. Writes each round to individual .txt files so they can appear on my stream. :) I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The 'while' loop will continue being ran till the condition is false, in which case it will leave the loop. therefore your function

```
while matchActive == True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        point1 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        point2 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)
```

will continue looping and never drop down to the next while loop which checks to see if the person has enough points to finish the game.

Your better off putting your game logic all within the main while loop.

```
while matchActive == True:
    # condition that will result in game finishing
    if point1 >= winRound:
        print("Round Won!")
        [.. quit out of the game..]

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        point1 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        point2 += 1
        sb()
        sleep(sleepTime)
```

Comment: okay that makes sense. I'm trying to clear this all up and make it easier to edit. I got it working now. Can I nest functions within other functions? Is this possible?

Comment: You cant nest functions within other functions, but you can call a function from within another function.

Comment: I think I need to go back and review functions. When I def addPoint(pX):
    pX += 1, then pass it along as addPoint(point1) literally in place of the point1 += 1, it stops adding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import keyboard
from time import sleep


#fighters
fighter1 = "Jim"
fighter2 = "Ryan"

#points
point1 = 0
point2 = 0
winRound = 3

#rounds
round1 = 0
round2 = 0
winMatch = 10

#sleep time
sleepTime = 1

#defines the match being on
matchActive = True
roundActive = True


#scoreboard
def sb1():
    print("Fighter:",fighter1,'\n','Points:',point1,'\n','Rounds:',round1)
def sb2():
    print("Fighter:",fighter2,'\n','Points:',point2,'\n','Rounds:',round2)

#functions

while matchActive == True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        point1 += 1
        sb1()
        sleep(sleepTime)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        point2 += 1
        sb2()
        sleep(sleepTime)

    if point1 == 3:
        round1 += 1
        point1 = 0
        point2 = 0
    elif point2 == 3:
        round2 += 1
        point1 = 0
        point2 = 0

    if round1 == winMatch or round2 == winMatch:
        print("Player #1 wins..." if round1 > round2 else "Player #2 wins...")
        matchActive = False
```

First of all, you missed to print the game stats for player two, because you had only a function `sb()` printing stats for player 1.
Next thing I've changed, is that your incrementing the points, but never increment your rounds. So now the points are deleted for both players if one player reach the `winRound` value. For this specific player the pointX value is incremented by 1.
The last change is the second while statement, which has been replaced by an if statement. You need to check whether one player reached the `winRound` value. This is done by the last if statement. If one of the players has won (in this case) 10 rounds, the winner is printed and the boolean value matchActive is set to False, which quits the while loop at next comparison of `matchActive == True`

Comment: I ignored player 2 stats on purpose. The goal was to get P1 to increment up, then move onwards. Thanks for the help. My issue was having 2 while statements. Apparently thats a big no no that none of the tutorials taught me. I kept thinking to myself, "do I have to write all this code under a single while statement"?

Turns out that is the case, and everything is running smoothly now.